# Call apex method from LWC with parameters after record creation

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter, js

I am inserting data to a custom object through LWC. I want to call an apex method from the JS with the Id of the newly created record and current user's email address.

Apex Method:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void checkRequestor(String requestorEmail, Id recordId) {
            
        if(requestorEmail.contains('@pwc.com')) {
            List<User> getUserId = [SELECT Id, Email, IsActive FROM User WHERE Email =: requestorEmail AND IsActive = true LIMIT 1];
            If(getUserId.size() > 0)
            { 
                try 
                {
                    List<Tender_Tracker_Case__Share> listCaseToShare = new List<Tender_Tracker_Case__Share>();
                    for(User userId : getUserId)   
                    {
                        Tender_Tracker_Case__Share caseToShare = new Tender_Tracker_Case__Share();
                        caseToShare.AccessLevel = 'Read';
                        caseToShare.UserOrGroupId = userId.Id;
                        caseToShare.ParentID = recordId;
                        caseToShare.RowCause = 'Manual';
                        listCaseToShare.add(caseToShare);
                    }
                    
                    if(listCaseToShare.size() > 0)
                    {
                        Insert listCaseToShare;
                    }
                    
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.debug(e.getMessage());
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
```

LWC JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import USER_EMAIL from '@salesforce/schema/User.Email';
import checkRequestor from '@salesforce/apex/TT_CaseEmailService.checkRequestor';

export default class CreateRecordLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track currentUserEmail;
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: Id, fields: [USER_EMAIL]}) 
    currentUserInfo({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.currentUserEmail = data.fields.Email.value;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error ;
        }
    }

handleCreate() {

    var fields = { 'Subject__c': this.template.querySelector("[data-field='Subject']").value, 
                   'TT_Case_Summary__c': this.template.querySelector("[data-field='CaseSummary']").value,
                };

    const recordInput = { 'apiName': 'Tender_Tracker_Case__c', fields };
    console.log(recordInput);

    createRecord(recordInput)
        .then((record) => {
            this.showToast('Success!!', 'Case created successfully!! ' + record.id, 'success', 'dismissable');
            this.showLoading = false;
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__recordPage",
                attributes: {
                actionName: 'view',
                objectApiName: 'Tender_Tracker_Case__c',
                recordId: record.id
                }
            });
            
            // call the apex method here and pass the parameters (email address and record id)
            @wire(checkRequestor, {requestorEmail : '$currentUserEmail', recordId : record.id});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.showLoading = false;
            console.log(error);
            this.showToast('Error!!', error.body.message, 'error', 'dismissable');
        });
        this.handleCancel();
        
}

}
```

In the JS code above, I am calling the apex method with the following line:

> @wire(checkRequestor, {requestorEmail : '$currentUserEmail', recordId
> : record.id});

I am new to LWC and don't know if this is the right way to call an apex method and pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
```

Setting `cacheable=true` disables DML operations, or, in other words, you can't persist any data to the database. Instead, you need to call this kind of Apex [imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-call-imperative.html):

```
checkRequestor({requestorEmail: this.currentUserEmail, recordId : record.id});
```

And make sure that `cacheable=false`.

Also, this sort of code is overly inefficient. To get the current user's Id for use in this kind of method, just call `UserInfo.getUserId()` in your Apex code.